# Left join in FetchXml?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, fetchxml

How do i do a left join using FetchXml?

Consider a simple SQL query like the following:

```sql
select person.name, address.city from person
left join address on person.addressid = address.addressid
```

How would something simple like this be done using FetchXml?
Currently my FetchXml query looks like the following:

```xml
<fetch mapping='logical'>
  <entity name='person'>
    <attribute name='name' />
    <link-entity name='address' from='addressid' to='addressid'>
      <attribute name='city' />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update your `<link-entity>` like so:

```
<link-entity name='address' from='addressid' to='addressid' link-type='outer'>
```

Comment: So -- implied in this is that `link-type='outer'` behaves NOT like a full outer join, but like a left outer join ?

Comment: Correct, it acts as a left outer join.